# Pytest-cov does not show term or html reports

Tags: pytest, python-3.6, coverage.py, pytest-cov

I am writing unit tests in python and trying to generate code coverage, but I am not seeing the term or HTML reports.

My Python **component structure** is as follows:

```
.
|-- README.md
|-- bin
|   |-- do_something.py
|   `-- do_something.sh
|-- junit.xml
|-- lib
|   `-- __init__.py
|-- pytest.ini
|-- requirements-dev.txt
|-- requirements.txt
|-- setup.py
`-- tests
    |-- __init__.py
    |-- env.py
    `-- test_do_something.py
```

**Source file:**

```
class DoSomething:
    def __init__(self, var=""):
        # define some initial variables
        self.var1 = var
        self.var2 = "Done"

    def do_something(self):
        var1 = self.var1 if self.var1 else "nothing"
        res = var1 + self.var2
        return res

def main(args):
    do_something_obj = DoSomething("Something")
    print(do_something_obj.do_something())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

**Test class and test cases:**

```
import bin.do_something as do_something

from bin.do_something import DoSomething


class TestDoSomething(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.a = "test"
    
    def test_do_something(self):
        do_something_test_obj = DoSomething(self.a)
        self.assertEquals("test Done", do_something_test_obj.do_something())
```

**CONFIGURATIONS:**

**.coveragerc**

```
[run]
    include =
         bin/*.py,lib/*.py
    omit =
         setup.py,tests/*.py
[report]
    
    exclude_lines =
         if __name__ == .__main__.:
```

**pytest.ini**

```
[pytest]
testpaths = tests
```

The test cases execute and pass by executing the following **command**:

```
python3 -m py.test --cov='.' --cov-report=xml --cov-report=term --junitxml=junit.xml -o junit_family=xunit2
```

However, no reports are generated, and I can see the following output.

```
================================================================================= test session starts ==================================================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.6.8, pytest-7.0.1, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: /home/my_component, configfile: pytest.ini, testpaths: tests
plugins: cov-4.0.0
collected 5 items

tests/test_do_something.py .....                                                                                                                                               [100%]

============================================================================= 1 passed, 1 warning in 0.09s =============================================================================
```

**ENVIRONMENT:**

```
linux:

CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)
5.4.201-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64
x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Python:
Python 3.6.8

pip packages and versions:

astroid (2.11.7)
attrs (22.1.0)
coverage (6.2)
dill (0.3.4)
importlib-metadata (4.8.3)
iniconfig (1.1.1)
isort (5.10.1)
lazy-object-proxy (1.7.1)
mccabe (0.7.0)
packaging (21.3)
pip (9.0.3)
platformdirs (2.4.0)
pluggy (1.0.0)
py (1.11.0)
pylint (2.13.9)
pyparsing (3.0.9)
pytest (7.0.1)
pytest-cov (4.0.0)
setuptools (39.2.0)
tomli (1.2.3)
typed-ast (1.5.4)
typing-extensions (4.1.1)
wrapt (1.14.1)
zipp (3.6.0)
```

Any idea why I don't see the term or HTML reports (I also issue a separate --cov-report=html option but don't see the HTML dir either)? Am I missing something?

**NOTE: I have tried deleting my virtual env and recreating several times, but I don't see a different outcome.**

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it's not showing reports, but remember you can always create the reports after the test run also:

```
python3 -m pytest --cov='.' --junitxml=junit.xml -o junit_family=xunit2
python3 -m coverage report
python3 -m coverage xml
python3 -m coverage html
```